# Modify controller in Opencart without touching the core?

Tags: php, polymorphism, opencart, extending-classes

Is there a way for developers to modify controller and model methods in Opencart without having to touch the core files? Much like the way WP has the *functions.php* file where you can modify the guts of WP without worrying about future upgrades overwriting your code.

Here are some examples which I think every developer needs to have in their Opencart toolkit:

- The ability to update values
- Run custom SQL queries
- Update logic of the program layer
- Extend the system further

Comment: Could you not override the class and reimplement the methods you want?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [vQmod](http://vqmod.com). This is the primary way that is used by most developers so as not to modify core code

Comment: vQmod is great but it has this _hacky_ feel to it I don't quite approve of. Especially since it uses XML when XML was designed for data transfer and not code storage.

Comment: A fair comment, but it's been largely adopted by the OC community on the whole and is the least intrusive method at present

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to modify the core minimally so that it can be extended easily.
And for anyone who is too late already, below an example to upgrade a modified core from 2.0.2.0 to master: (otherwise I'd suggest forking opencart and using rebase!)

```
git clone https://github.com/opencart/opencart
cd opencart
git checkout 2.0.2.0 #insert tag with your current version. Mine was 2.0.2.0
cd upload

#Note: sed strips paths for 'upload/' (opencart)
git diff 2.0.2.0 master > ~/patch-to-newest-version.diff | sed "s/+++ b\/upload\//+++ b\//" | sed "s/--- a\/upload\//--- a\//"
#       I chose ^master^ but you'd better use a stable version.

cd to-your-modified-(opencart)core
patch -p1 < ~/patch-to-newest-version.diff

#..time to resolve the conflicts.. hopefully not much. Good luck.
```

(if anyone knows a better way to patch a modified core, please comment. Especially because it is not nice to keep working in a '/upload' folder... use a sparse checkout or s/t?